# Debug the full output of QR code reader?

Tags: debug, qr-code

In my Android device, I use app "A" to scan a static QR code and the app will show the result.

If I use a regular QR code reader app, the QR code will show as: "checkin:XXXstaticID"

Is it possible to know the full execution command of app "A", so I can just execute that command or open the URL without have to scan the QR code?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, there's no other way than reverse engineering app A to know the logic.

Comment: @AndrewT. I thought we could capture the activities from app A like using sysinternal procmon on Windows. Ok I will try the hardest way. hope it is not obfuscated.